# JavaScript CSS animation only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an bank application that has a super cool hand come down and drop a coin into a piggy bank. Problem is, the hand only drops the coin once then stops working.

Here is my code:

```
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

body {
  background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {}
  100% {margin-top:-220px;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  90%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0;}
}

#hand {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-120px;
  margin-top:-350px;
  background-image:url("../images/hand.png");
  opacity:0;
}

#pigBox {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height:600px;
  width:500px;
  margin-top:250px;
  position:relative;

  img {
    margin:0px 50px;
  }

}

input[type=text] {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-size:2em;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2px;
}

#deposit {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2em;
  clear:left;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:pink;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color:white;
  }
}

#withdraw {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2em;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:pink;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color:white;
  }
}

label {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2.5em;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:300px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

document.getElementById('balance').value = "1000"

var balance = document.getElementById('balance').value;
var deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');
var withdraw = document.getElementById('withdraw');
var hand = document.getElementById('hand');

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);
withdraw.addEventListener('click', withdrawCash);

function depositCash() {
  var depositAmt = prompt('How much would you like to deposit?');

  if(depositAmt != Number(depositAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
  }
  else if (Number(depositAmt) < 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');
  }

  hand.style.animation = 'moveDown 1.5s ease-in-out, fadeIn 1.5s ease-in-out';
  balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}

function withdrawCash() {
  var withdrawAmt = prompt('How much you you like to withdraw?');

  if(withdrawAmt != Number(withdrawAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
  }
  else if (Number(withdrawAmt) < 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');
  }
  else if(withdrawAmt > balance) {
    return alert("Your balance isn't large enough to withdraw that amount!")
  }


  balance = Number(balance) - Number(withdrawAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}

<section id="pigBox">
      <div id="hand"></div><!-- end of hand-->
      <img src="images/pig.png" />
      <label>Balance: </label><input type="text" id="balance" />
      <button id="deposit"> Deposit </button>
      <button id="withdraw"> Withdraw </button>
  </section><!-- end of pigBox-->
```

[image]

```
<a href="http://imgur.com/FxwmGFi"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FxwmGFi.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>
```

notice the hand.style animation when you deposit money into the piggy bank.

Any thoughts guys?

Thank you!

Comment: self-contained example plz? I want to see the supercool hand as well :-)

Comment: How can i host my pictures and css on here ;)

Comment: @Brixsta You can add images to your question, and it should assign them an imgur link.  For the CSS, just post that like you did with the JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: you can also use a fake image with a data uri and css background-image if you don't want to upload the image

Comment: @Brixsta you also have another issue... The first time your code grabs the balance, it gets it as a string, so if you initially try a withdrawal (anything > 1) it will say you don't have enough $.  Wrapping your `balance` variable with `parseInt()` will fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [CSS animations don't automatically restart](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/). In particular because you didn't define a time loop, so it just executes once.

One approach is for you to use .addClass('x').removeClass('x') to retrigger an animation defined on class X.

.addClass() is jQuery of course. You can do the same in vanilla JS using, for example, hand.className += ' my-animation'; and resetting at the top of the method as per below.

```js
//ref: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

document.getElementById('balance').value = "1000"

var balance = document.getElementById('balance').value;
var deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');
var withdraw = document.getElementById('withdraw');
var hand = document.getElementById('hand');

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);
withdraw.addEventListener('click', withdrawCash);

function depositCash() {
  hand.className = 'randoImage';
  var depositAmt = prompt('How much would you like to deposit?');

  if(depositAmt != Number(depositAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
  }
  else if (Number(depositAmt) < 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');
  }

  hand.className += ' my-animation';
  balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}

function withdrawCash() {
  var withdrawAmt = prompt('How much you you like to withdraw?');

  if(withdrawAmt != Number(withdrawAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
  }
  else if (Number(withdrawAmt) < 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');
  }
  else if(withdrawAmt > balance) {
    return alert("Your balance isn't large enough to withdraw that amount!")
  }


  balance = Number(balance) - Number(withdrawAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}
```

```css
.randoImage {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7);
}

* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {}
  100% {margin-top:-220px;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  90%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0;}
}

#hand {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-120px;
  margin-top:-350px;
  /*background-image:url("../images/hand.png");*/
  opacity:0;
}

#pigBox {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height:600px;
  width:500px;
  margin-top:250px;
  position:relative;

  img {
    margin:0px 50px;
  }

}

input[type=text] {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-size:2em;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2px;
}

#deposit {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2em;
  clear:left;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:pink;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color:white;
  }
}

#withdraw {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2em;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:pink;
  border:solid 2px pink;
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color:white;
  }
}

label {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
  font-size:2.5em;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:300px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

.my-animation {
  animation: moveDown 1.5s ease-in-out, fadeIn 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section id="pigBox">
      <div class="randoImage" id="hand"></div><!-- end of hand-->
      <img class="randoImage" />
      <!--<img src="images/pig.png" />-->
      <label>Balance: </label><input type="text" id="balance" />
      <button id="deposit"> Deposit </button>
      <button id="withdraw"> Withdraw </button>
  </section><!-- end of pigBox-->
```

Comment: Your solution only executes once. Using IE11.

Comment: Fixed I think, please check. Now with no jQuery needed!

Comment: It works wonderfully. Can you elaborate on the logic? Why does hand.className = randomImage; work so well? Is it because it some how refreshes the hand div?

Comment: hand.className = 'randoImage'; is effectively removing the 'my-animation' class. The next time ' my-animation' is added, it retriggers the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete style for Hand after animation (add 3 line to your script):

...

**var myHand = false;**

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);

withdraw.addEventListener('click', withdrawCash);

function depositCash() {

**if (myHand) clearTimeout(myHand);**

...

hand.style.animation = 'moveDown 1.5s ease-in-out, fadeIn 1.5s ease-in-out';

balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);

document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;

**myHand = setTimeout(function(){hand.style.animation = '';}, 2000);**

}

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

For those using jQuery, here is my solution.

I realized that if we string together **.addClass().removeClass()**, jQuery interprets and negates the two commands, resulting in no change. So I suggest a workaround using Timeout function:

let **animationTimeout**

**clearTimeout**( animationTimeout )

$('#animatedElement').**addClass**('animation')

animationTimeout  = **setTimeout**(() => {$('#animatedElement').**removeClass**('animation')}, animationDuration)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple solution with animated svgs is to Load the image with a random query like for example;

Assuming a javascript environment with an existing function loadImage,

loadImage('image.svg?u='+new Date().getMilliseconds());

You trick the browser into thinking its not the same file and animation begins.

Comment: is not a .gif a better solution ? are not you generating unnecesary traffic?